# Can't see maps after including google map api and geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

It doesn nto display any errors or warning other than no key warning but still does not display map on my webpage. It only displays text values of latitude and longitude which means getlocation() and showposition() are working .

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MY FORM</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="getLocation()">trysd</button>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=Function.prototype"
    ></script>
    <script>
      let x = document.getElementById('map')
      function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition)
        } else {
          x.innerHTML = 'Geolocation is not supported by this browser.'
        }
      }

      function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML =
          'Latitude: ' +
          position.coords.latitude +
          '<br>Longitude: ' +
          position.coords.longitude
        var mapProp = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(
            position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude
          ),
          zoom: 5,
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapProp)
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a fixed `width` and `height` with CSS or inline styles to your `<div id="map">` element.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      width: 800px;
      height: 800px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```